# Редактирование TableView

Tags: java, javafx

Хочу сделать так, чтобы можно было редактировать данные прямо в таблице. Но при вызове методы setOnEditCommit для обоих столбцов пишет: неверный параметр в лямбда-вырадении, ожидает Event а видит CellEditEvent.

```
package controllers;

import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import objects.Word;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    public TableColumn wordCol;

    @FXML
    public TableColumn translateCol;

    @FXML
    public TableView table;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        table.setEditable(true);
        Callback<TableColumn<Word, String>, TableCell<Word, String>> cellFactory = (TableColumn<Word, String> tc) -> new EditingCell();

        wordCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(""));
        wordCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
        wordCol.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<Word, String> e) -> {
            ((Word) e.getTableView().getItems().get(e.getTablePosition().getRow())).setWord(e.getNewValue());
        });

        translateCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(""));
        translateCol.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
        translateCol.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<Word, String> e) -> {
            ((Word) e.getTableView().getItems().get(e.getTablePosition().getRow())).setTranslate(e.getNewValue());
        });
    }

    class EditingCell extends TableCell<Word, String> {

        private TextField textField;

        public EditingCell(){}

        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            if(!isEmpty()) {
                super.startEdit();
                createTextField();
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
                textField.selectAll();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();

            setText((String) getItem());
            setGraphic(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                if (isEditing()) {
                    if (textField != null) {
                        textField.setText(getString());
                    }
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(textField);
                } else {
                    setText(getString());
                    setGraphic(null);
                }
            }
        }

        private void createTextField() {
            textField = new TextField(getString());
            textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap()* 2);
            textField.focusedProperty().addListener(
                    (ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0,
                     Boolean arg1, Boolean arg2) -> {
                        if (!arg2) {
                            commitEdit(textField.getText());
                        }
                    });
        }

        private String getString() {
            return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Вот класс Word

```
public class Word {

    private SimpleStringProperty word;
    private SimpleStringProperty translate;

    public Word(String word, String translate) {
        this.word = new SimpleStringProperty(word);
        this.translate = new SimpleStringProperty(translate);
    }

    public Word() {
        this.word = new SimpleStringProperty(null);
        this.translate = new SimpleStringProperty(null);
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty wordProperty() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word.set(word);
    }

    public String getTranslate() {
        return translate.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty translateProperty() {
        return translate;
    }

    public void setTranslate(String translate) {
        this.translate.set(translate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Параметризуйте колонки `wordCol` и `translateCol` параметрами `<Word, String>`.
2. Вместо  `((Word) e.getTableView().getItems().get(e.getTablePosition().getRow())).setBlaBlaBla` сделайте так:

   `if (e.getTablePosition() != null) {
           e.getRowValue().setBlaBlaBla(e.getNewValue);
       }`

**UPDATE**

Вам необходимо написать так

```
    @FXML
    public TableColumn<Word, String> wordCol;

    @FXML
    public TableColumn<Word, String> translateCol;
```

Comment: wordCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("word"));
        wordCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Word>forTableColumn());
        wordCol.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<Word, String> e) -> {
            if(e.getTablePosition() != null) {
                e.getRowValue().setWord(e.getNewValue());
            }
        });
      Немного переписал, но не помогло (такая же ошибка). Правда, я не понял, что значит параметризировать колонки? Разве метод setCellValueFactory не задает тип ячейки?

Comment: @ДенисСавенко см апдейт ответа

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за ответ :) Теперь все работает!

Comment: @ДенисСавенко Если ответ решает вашу проблему, то его необходимо поменить как верный